# Uploading multiple files using Zend_Form_Element_File and HTML5's multiple attribute

Tags: forms, html, zend-framework

I want to upload multiple images using `Zend_Form_Element_File` with the HTML attribute `multiple`. Setting up the element works intuitively:

```
$form->addElement(new Zend_Form_Element_File(
    'images',
    array('label' => 'Images:', 'multiple' => 'multiple')
));
```

When I get a reference to the input field in my upload page und do a `$input->receive()`, it only saves one of the selected files.

When I search for something like "Zend_Form_Element_File multiple files", I only get results that show the use of `Zend_Form_Element_File::setMultiFile()`, which isn't what I'm looking for.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just found the answer to my own question:

**You have to set 'isArray' on the input element to true, either in the options array when constructing the element (`new Zend_Form_Input_File('images', array('isArray' => true))`) or via the isArray() method (`$input->setIsArray(true)`).**

Some background info and how I finally found this solution:

First, I realized that I have to apend square brackets to the element's name for multiple file uploads to work, e.g. `images[]`. I don't know if that's the HTML specification or if that's something PHP requires, but that's how it should work in this case.

My next problem was that `Zend_Form_Element` removes the brackets when I try to set them with the `name` property. Finally, I stumbled upon the [answer by Matthew Weier O'Phinney](http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/Zend-Form-and-square-brackets-in-elements-name-td661888.html) himself: `isArray` appends the `[]` for you.

Comment: Thanks for this! Been searching how to do this for at least an hour! :)